# Average of multiple subjects

Tags: average

I have a table like this and I need average of each subjects of all students(here 2 only)

**Student Subject Marks**

```
John    Maths   80
John    Science 70
John    Social  90
Raju    Maths   90
Raju    Science 80
Raju    Social  70
```

o/p should like this

**Subject Average**

```
Maths    85
Science  75
Social   80
```

Comment: What is being asked?

Comment: what exactly do you want? there is not question in your post. Just some data

Comment: `(SubjectScore1 + SubjectScore2 / 2)`

Comment: @ Hanky: I need sql Query not a maths formula

Answer (score 0):

You may use below query:

```
select studentInfo.Subject, avg(studentInfo.marks) from studentInfo group by studentInfo.Subject
```

Please refer below link:
[enter link description here](http://www.plus2net.com/sql_tutorial/sql_avg.php)

Comment: Select Subject, avg(Marks) as Average from table. Does this work??

Comment: This is hint. Basically you have to apply group by clause on subjects and need to use avg function. If you provide your table structure in well format I will give you query.